# Using getElementsByClassName() Method to get first x amount of elements matching class

Tags: javascript

What is the correct method to use to get a list of all elements matching a class then return only say the first 3 items matching that class? Eg.

```
<div class="reviewContainer"></div>
<div class="reviewContainer"></div>
<div class="reviewContainer"></div>
<div class="reviewContainer"></div>
```

And return only the first 3 elements. Basically I want to select the top 3 items at the beginning of the reviewContainer list only.

Comment: There's no "_correct_" method for doing this, there are many good ways.

Comment: [Document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). Then from that list pick first 3 probably with `Array.from(nodelist)`

Answer (score 3):

I'd turn the HTMLCollection into an array, then `slice` the first 3 elements from the array:

```
const firstThreeFoos = [...document.getElementsByClassName('foo')]
  .slice(0, 3);
```

If you need to support obsolete, EOL browsers, spread syntax and `const` won't work:

```
var firstThreeFoos = Array.prototype.slice.call(
  document.getElementsByClassName('foo'),
  0,
  3
);
```

Comment: `const firstThreeFoos = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('foo'), 0, 3);` avoids a for/of like iteration over the collection that also might not have Symbol.iterator in older browsers 

Comment: Perfect, most usable, thank you for pointing me in the right direction even though there isn't one 'correct' method!

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi thank you, so does this create the array and slice all selected elements on load without iteration over each?

Comment: @ZADorkMan Given the information available, there's no way to avoid selecting *all* matching elements first. There might be a way to select the first 3 elements of that class given the HTML, though, using `querySelectorAll` (unless there's no real way to differentiate the 3rd element from the 4th, etc - but if that's the case, 3 sounds like a magic number, which is a code smell)

Comment: I am using, 

`var firstThreeFoos = Array.prototype.slice.call(
  document.getElementsByClassName('reviewContainer'),
  0,1
);

document.getElementById("reviewsSnap").innerHTML = firstThreeFoos;`

But when running it get, [object HTMLDivElement] output, I tried `firstThreeFoos.toString()` but still no luck, please help me understand what I am doing wrong, is it because I the array has been sliced? 

Here is the Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/x1cLhtvo/

Comment: What sort of output do you want? The HTML in the question doesn't look to have anything inside the divs

Answer (score 2):

You can use a query selector to select any amount of sequential elements by combining two `nth-child` pseudo classes, like so:

```
const reviews = document.querySelectorAll('.reviewContainer:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+3)');
```

Where the constant (`1`) in the first `nth-child` selector is the index to start to select elements, and the constant (`3`) in the second `nth-child` selector is the index where to stop the selecting. These indices are 1-based.

Notice, that you can make this dynamic by replacing the constants with variables within the selector string. This is not also strictly the same as using `getElementsByClassName`, because this selector provides the first `.reviewContent` element being the first child in its parent.